# How to use animationDidStop in swift

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift.
Say I have an array of UIImage loaded with image1 to image4. Assign to a UIImageView.
I set the animation to repeat only once. Once the animation stop playing I would like a function to be called, preferably able to attach parameters when calling.

How can this be done? My research only let me know I may have to do
override func animationDidStop

If I have more than one set of animation happening at the same time, how do I know which set of animation is calling?

Thanks in advance
sweekim